# MongoDB Select distinct - returns more files

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MySQL you can query something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, Address FROM table WHERE OtherColumn='x';
```

Is there any way to do the same in MongoDB?
I can't do this:

```
db.getCollection('table').distinct('Name',{OtherColumn:'x'})
```

But it returns an array with only the Name. But doesn't the Address.

Is there any way to do it without make 2 querys to MongoDB?

```
db.getCollection('table').distinct('Name',{OtherColumn:'x'})
db.getCollection('table').distinct('Address',{OtherColumn:'x'})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) is not the right method to use here if you don't want to perform two queries. Instead, you need to use the [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method, [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents and use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) accumulator operator to return distinct value for each field.

```js
db.getCollection('table').aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "Name": { "$addToSet": "$Name",  }, 
        "Address": { "$addToSet": "$Address" } 
    }} 
])
```

Comment: That's the answer, but only a thing. To avoid repeated Name or Address: db.getCollection('table').aggregate([ 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": null, 
        "Name": { "$first": "$Name",  }, 
        "Address": { "$first": "$Address" } 
    }} 
]). Thanks

Comment: If you use `$first` your query will return one document and I don't think that, it is what you want.

Comment: Yes, because it's returns 3 Names and 4 Address for example. After use $first it works. Thanks for your example. Regards.